# Google Apps Scripts - server-side function calling

Tags: html, google-apps-script, serverside-javascript

I run the doGet() function. It creates a modal dialog on a spreadsheet. It will show a "Close" and "Make Copy" button where the latter will run a server-side function, doSomething(), that makes a copy of a template. Regardless of whether I attach the function to a button or run it straight in a script tag, it refuses to run. Is there anyway to fix or at the least debug this?

**Code.gs**

```
function doGet() {
  return SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showModalDialog(HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('Index'), 'Report');
}

function doSomething() {
  var file = template.makeCopy();
  file.setName('NEW FILE NAME')
  google.script.host.close()
}
```

**Index.html**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <base target="_top">
        <script>
            google.script.run.doSomething()
        </script>
      </head>
      <body>
          <input type="button" value="Close" onclick="google.script.host.close()"/>
          <input type="button" value="Make Copy" onclick="google.script.run.doSomething();" />
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: I'm not sure the `template`varialbe can be global in your case. I thing @tehhowch is pointing a good thing also

Comment: Check Stackdriver for unhandled exceptions. Note that doGet is a trigger meant for accessing a published webapp, not a sidebar, and probably has no access to your UI instance.

Answer (score 1):

1. doGet() is a reserved word for web apps.
2. SpreadsheetApp.getUi only could be used on bounded projects
3. google.script.host.close() is a client-side method that only works for dialogs and sidebars not for web apps.

**Suggestions:**

As your project is a bounded project,

- change the name of the doGet() function.
- Remove `google.script.host.close()` from doSomething()
- Remove

  ```
  <script>
      google.script.run.doSomething()
  </script>
  ```
- Once you make the above changes add menu to call your renamed function. If still doesn't work look for errors at the browser console for client-side errors and to Stackdriver logs for server-side errors.

Quotes

> `doGet(e)` runs when a user visits a web app or a program sends an HTTP GET request to a web app.

---

> `google.script.host` is an asynchronous client-side JavaScript API that can interact with dialogs or sidebars in Google Docs, Sheets, or Forms that contain [HTML-service pages](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/). To execute server-side functions from client-side code, use `google.script.run`. For more information, see the [guide to communicating with server functions in HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/communication).

References

- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/
- https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/host#close

Answer (score 0):

In Apps Script, the doGet() and doPost() functions are strictly for sending HTTP requests to GAS-based web apps. Spreadsheet-bound scripts can be published as web apps - however, according to the docs

> To create a web app with the HTML service, your code must include a
>   doGet() function that tells the script how to serve the page. The
>   function must return an HtmlOutput object, as shown in this example.

In your case, the showModalDialog() method returns 'void'. Also,

> Unlike a web app, a script that creates a user interface for a
>   document, spreadsheet, or form does not need a doGet() function
>   specifically, and you do not need to save a version of your script or
>   deploy it. Instead, the function that opens the user interface must
>   pass your HTML file as an HtmlOutput object to the showModalDialog())
>   or showSidebar() methods of the Ui object for the active document,
>   form, or spreadsheet.

Long story short, you don't need to deploy your script as a web app. Instead, you should put the UI building code directly into your main function and, finally, tie that function to the button.